# How to cat file from output of other command?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat, more

If I do:

```
perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/WWW/Mechanize.pm
```

How can I, in one line, print to the screen the contents of the file given by the top command?  I was hoping I could do something like:

```
perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize | cat | more
```

Comment: Or using xargs: `perldoc -l WW::Mechanize | xargs more`

Comment: `perldoc WWW::Mechanize | cat`.  or `PAGER=cat perldoc WWW::Mechanize`.  and use `perldoc -t` to produce plain text without the escape codes and other formatting that prettifies the output for `less`.

Comment: @cas `perldoc WWW::Mechanize | cat` does not output the contents of the source file.  I don't understand how you can have 23k rep when you misunderstand a simple question.

Comment: perhaps because i usually ignore unclear or ambiguous questions.  but mostly i posted my comment because there was no point repeating "use xargs" or "use command substitution" and nobody else had covered the obvious "if all you want to do is view or stream the docs without a pager getting in the way then just pipe it".

Comment: @cas The question is clear. I want to output the contents of the file path generated by `perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize`.  Your suggestion to simply pipe it to `cat` does not solve the problem.

Comment: berating volunteers over trivia is such a good way of encouraging people to help you.  good luck with your life. bye.

Comment: Your question was ambiguous.  I made a comment that addressed one possible interpretation of your ambiguity.  That, apparently, is worth berating someone about with a snide comment about reputation scores (instead of, say, just ignoring it - or even just *not being a jerk about it* - as a normal person would).  As i said, good luck with your life - with your obnoxious attitude, you'll need lots of it.  And try expressing yourself clearly and unambiguously - it's YOUR responsibility as the writer to clarify or eliminate any potentially ambiguous points.

Comment: @cas Please point out how my question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using command substitution, like this:

`more "$(perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize)"`

The command in parentheses will be run first in a subshell. The output will then be sent to `more`.

The quotes are included to prevent issues with the more general case: if the output contained whitespace or globbing characters, for instance.

As an example, if the output of `perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize` contained a space, as in `/usr/local/lib/perl5/site perl/5.16.3/WWW/Mechanize.pm`, you would get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site: No such file or directory
perl/5.16.3/WWW/Mechanize.pm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do quote it though i.e. `"$(perldoc -l WWW::Mechanize)"` else it will break in the more general case where names may include whitespace

Comment: Point taken. I've updated my answer.